# How to construct a 2 Ply Beam with screws:

Tags: beam

I need to make a 2 ply 2x8 beam, but I don't have a nail gun. I have seen a lot of articles on how to make a 2 ply beam by nailing in a double row pattern down the 2 2x8s (or 2x10, etc.), but how can I do this with screws? Do I use Faster Master flatLOK screws in a W pattern (with liquid nails between the boards of course)? It is not clear what Faster Master screws to use when constructing a 2 ply beam. Thanks!

Comment: I'll let the pros answer. But off the top of my head, I'd think any brand of flat-head screws, 2-1/2" long, screwed in from both sides, should be *very* strong. Might want to drill pilot holes first to minimize the chance of any splitting.

Comment: IIRC the usual issue with screws .vs. nails is relative shear strength. Do you own a hammer? This is not a particularly difficult nailing job...

Comment: Nail guns are for wimps, use a regular hammer.  It will become easy after 20 or 40 beams.  Can also practice lalochezia when you hit your thumb.

Comment: Liquid nails is a panel adhesive, its not suited to structural work, as it does not have any fire rating. (also it softens if you heat it)  it's not needed, nail lamination just uses nails.

Comment: if you really want to use screws take a look at structural screws - simpson strongtie have some and they have install guides.

Comment: [Schedule for laminating LVLs](https://wesbeam.com/Wesbeam/media/Documents/Tech%20Data%20Sheets/WESB0500_MultiSection-TIS.pdf). Everything's in metric though. Tells you minimum edge distance, diameter, and number to use. Do not stagger. Use chalk lines and a square.